# How to convert this query in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How do I convert this query to laravel form?

[image]

Comment: Laravel uses Eloquent ORM, so you would need the relevant models created and then you could query using relationships and sub-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somthing along the lines of:

```
Stocks::where('shop_id', $client_id)
->where(function ($query) use ($client_id, $ware_cd) {
    $query->where('ware_id',
    DB::raw(
     'select ware_id from t_ware where shop_id=' . $client_id . ' and ware_cd=' . $ware_cd
     )
   );
})
->distinct()
->get();
```